# How to get other contact details in harvest api using php

Tags: php, api, harvest

I have written as

```
<?php
 require_once 'HarvestAPI.php';

  /* Register Auto Loader */
   spl_autoload_register(array('HarvestAPI', 'autoload'));

   $api = new HarvestAPI();
   $api->setUser( "nida.amin@gmail.com" );
   $api->setPassword( "aaabbb12345" );
   $api->setAccount( "heavenscompany" );

   $api->setRetryMode( HarvestAPI::RETRY );
   $api->setSSL(true);

   $result = $api->getClients();
   foreach( $result->data as $client ) {
   if( $result->isSuccess() ) {
   echo $client->get( "name" );
   echo $client->details;
   }
  }
 ?>
```

I am very new to Harvest API. Please help me how to get other contact details of the client like email, mobile no's, office...etc in Harvest API in php?

Answer (score 0):

You might find the email address in the client details. Try the following:

```
var_dump($client->details);die();
```

Then you should get an output of what is in the details variable. Hopefully it will be an array and you can extract the email address out of it.

Comment: No, I think $client-details is not an array as it displays text (address field of the Client)

Comment: What if you var_dump the whole $client object? Do you find an email address in the output?

Comment: So it seems that either your client object de facto has no email address or the API has no functionality to return it.